# Select during vs. after insert produces different results

Tags: python, sqlite

My database is written to every second during certain hours. It's also read from during same hours, every minute.

The read outputs different values during operational hours vs. after hours. Might be data is not written when I read. How to fix this or make sure data for last minute is complete before reading? Would a different database do better?

How I am reading:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(f'{loc_tick}/tick.db',
detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES, timeout=20, isolation_level=None)
select_statement = f"select * from symfut WHERE 
timestamp >= date('now', '-10 days')"
m1df = pd.read_sql(select_statement, conn)
```

Write:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('tick.db', 
detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES, timeout=20,isolation_level=None)
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('PRAGMA journal_mode=wal')
c.execute('PRAGMA wal_autocheckpoint = 100')
c.execute('INSERT INTO symfut (timestamp, c, b, a) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',
                  (timestamp, c, b, a))
```

Comment: Sqlite does not support concurrency...so if you need high traffic, this is not the DB you should use...I haven't used it outside of testing an idea, but I'd almost guarantee if your bottleneck is in your DB, if you change to Postgres (as one example) you'd be better

Comment: @ViaTech, I understand. Postgres or some other like MongoDB I am researching. How to ensure I have the correct data till last minute is also a great concern.

Comment: Question would benefit by adding the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I want to reinforce @ViaTech's excellent answer.  SQLite was designed to be simple and lightweight.  It was not designed for real-time use or concurrent access.  They make few guarantees, and in your situation you need the guarantees that a client/server database provides.  It's just the wrong tool for this job.  Personally, in a one-writer-many-reader situation, I probably would have chosen a simple CSV.  I can append lines without impacting readers.

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks. I am researching which DB to go with. A CSV was the solution I was using for a long time, switched to a database as the number of tables increased.

Answer (score 0):

While SQLite does not support full concurrency, it doesn't mean that it can't correctly address your needs. Using Postgress or a different DB could actually worsen the problem.

Sqlite is highly reliable and is absolutely deterministic in its behaviour and is fully capable of handling scenarios with one writer and many readers, if all the processes are on the same machine and the db file is not on a network.

When a write transaction ends, even in WAL mode, every subsequent read is guaranteed to read the updated values.

Your problem could be related to this:

1. when you are reading, the write transaction is still open and not completed. This can happen if reader and writer are separate processes which are not synchronized. Using a different DB will not resolve it, you must provide a synchronization mechanism.
2. When you write you provide a timestamp. How is it calculated? Is it in UTC timezone? How much time passes from when you calculate the timestamp and when you write it? Note that the INSERT may have to wait up to your timeout before executing.
3. When you read you use 'now - 10 days', which is calulated in UTC timezone and resolved at the time the SELECT is executed, without any delay. Combine this with the timestamp INSERTED and this could make some difference between operational hours and after hours.
4. If you INSERT a row every second, your SELECT will return hundreds of thousands of rows and will probably need a few seconds to execute. Since Sqlite guarantees consistency, rows inserted while the select executes will not be considered. This could be another point of difference between executing the select while rows are inserted or in the off hours.

Comment: Point 3, this might an issue although when I print the data from the response/read it seems to be in line with what I expect. The write timestamp is GMT+5:30. Thank you. I am trying to investigate the issue further.

Comment: If write timestamp is localtime, then in the SELECT you should use `date('now', 'localtime', '-10 days')` for a correct comparison.